# Is it possible to reproduce the attached figure in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to reproduce the attached figure in latex without any other information? If possible, please help...
[image]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is possible but very cumbersome to punch in all the annotations. Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I want to get Gamma_0 and Gamma_epsilon curves only and unable to start . Don't know how to do that.

Comment: How are these curves defined, mathematically?

Comment: @Bernard Suppose the following \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,0) node[right] {$u$};
      \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,1) node[above] {$v$};
      \draw[scale=1,domain=0:1,smooth,variable=\x,blue] plot ({\x},{-(-1+\x)*(\x+0.25)/1});
      \draw[scale=1,domain=0:1,smooth,variable=\x,red]  plot ({\x},{\x});
                        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Comment: This code has nothing to do with $\Gamma_0$ and $\Gamma_\epsilon$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very well, then. Here is a *start* that draws the curves but does not punch in all the labels.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,declare function={f(\x)=4-0.5*(\x-2)*(\x-2);}]
 \draw[<->] (0,4.5) node[above left]{$v$} |- (6.5,0) node[below right] {$u$};
 \draw[densely dashed] (0,2) parabola bend (2,4) ({2+2*sqrt(2)},0)
    (0,2) node[left]{$Q$}  (2,4) node[below]{$P$}
    (0.9,0) to[out=90,in=-110] (1.4,4.5);
 \draw[green!60!black,thick] (0.2,4.05) to[bend right=5]
 (0.2,{f(4.7)+0.05}) --  plot[variable=\x,domain=4.7:2]
  (\x+0.05,{f(\x)+0.05}) -- cycle;
 \draw[purple,thick,>={Stealth[round]},postaction=decorate,
    decoration={markings,
    mark=at position 0.125 with {\arrow[black]{>}},
    mark=at position 0.4 with {\arrow[black]{>.>}},
    mark=at position 0.7 with {\arrow[black]{>}},
    mark=at position 0.925 with {\arrow[black]{>.>}},
    }] (0,4) --
 (0,{f(4.65)}) --  plot[variable=\x,domain=4.65:2]
  (\x,{f(\x)}) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Next time, they will throw a captcha at the site and ask whether it is possible to reproduce it. (BTW, the answer here is essentially “yes” :-P).

Comment: @frougon I agree, and said so in [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525640/is-it-possible-to-reproduce-the-attached-figure-in-latex#comment1329588_525640). I focused on the less repetitive part.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat How to know about the f(\x)=4-0.5*(\x-2)*(\x-2)

Comment: @user1942348 I do not understand the question. The plot seems to have a parabola shape, and that's a parabola.

Comment: ok... thanks...

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Can it be possible to make the three corner points of the green curve a bit smooth and rounded?

Comment: @user1942348 `\draw[green!60!black,thick,rounded corners] (0.2,4.05) to[bend right=5]
 (0.2,{f(4.7)+0.05}) --  plot[variable=\x,domain=4.7:2]
  (\x+0.05,{f(\x)+0.05}) -- cycle;`?

Comment: Nice... Thank you...