# Error for a boxed figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Thanks to  Schrödinger's cat for the code in [Is it possible to reproduce the attached figure in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525640/is-it-possible-to-reproduce-the-attached-figure-in-latex/525646?noredirect=1#comment1330176_525646)

I want to put the following figure in a rectangular box whose sides are two axes and two straight lines parallel to the axes. Also x and y should be written at the bottom (in middle) of the corresponding axis. All coming perfectly. But some problems are there

> 1. At (0,2) $Q$ is not visible --I want to write Q to the left of y-axis
> 2. At mark=at position 0.125 with {\arrow[black]{>}} -- the left part of arrow is not visible

```
  \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x)=4-0.5*(\x-2)*(\x-2);}]
 \begin{axis}[grid=minor, xmin=0, xmax=5, ymin=0, ymax=4.5,
         xlabel=$x$, ylabel={$y$},
         xtick = {}, ytick = {},
         scale=1, restrict y to domain=0:4.5]

 \draw[densely dashed] (0,2) parabola bend (2,4) ({2+2*sqrt(2)},0)
    (0,2) node[left]{$Q$}  (2,4) node[below]{$P$}
    (0.9,0) to[out=90,in=-110] (1.4,4.5);
 \draw[green!60!black,thick] (0.2,4.05) to[bend right=5]
 (0.2,{f(4.7)+0.05}) --  plot[variable=\x,domain=4.7:2]
  (\x+0.05,{f(\x)+0.05}) -- cycle;
 \draw[purple,thick,>={Stealth[round]},postaction=decorate,
    decoration={markings,
    mark=at position 0.125 with {\arrow[black]{>}},
    mark=at position 0.4 with {\arrow[black]{>.>}},
    mark=at position 0.7 with {\arrow[black]{>}},
    mark=at position 0.925 with {\arrow[black]{>.>}},
    }] (0,4) --
 (0,{f(4.65)}) --  plot[variable=\x,domain=4.65:2]
  (\x,{f(\x)}) -- cycle;
 \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How to solve the two problems?

Comment: Make sure you copy everything when you copy an example, you're missing `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}`, add it and your code compiles just fine.

Comment: @Zarko Ok Thanks ....

Comment: @Zarko No error but two problems are still persist...

Comment: Just add `clip=false` to the options of the axis.

Comment: Great ... Thanks a lot